# Reference on group-presentations

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory, free-abelian-group

I'm looking for an introduction to free abelian groups and their presentation, specifically to understand notation such as:

$G=^{ab}\left\langle a,b,c \text{  } | a + 2b + 3c = −a − 2b − 7c = 0 \right\rangle$

and how starting from this presentation, you would be able to obtain an isomorphism between G and the direct product of cyclic groups

Thanks in advance

Comment: That is not a standard notation. Those two equalities, are they supposed to mean three different relations? Also the $X^{ab}$ typically should be after the group definition. Why is it attached to the equality sign? Very untidy notation. Where did you get that from?

Comment: They're supposed to denote two different relations; I got this from some notes a professor from my university wrote

Comment: Again regarding the equalities, it's probably a quick way to write something such as ⟨,, |+2+3 =0, −−2−7=0⟩

Comment: Yeah, maybe. Still lazy and untidy. Typical of university professors. Either way, you have a system of equations over integers. Solve it. For example $c=0$ here just by adding those equations, and then $a=-2b$ which means that $a$ generator can be removed as well. You are left with $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Do you have any reference for the theory around such exercises? Like how do you arrive from defining finitely generated abelian groups as quotients of free groups to that presentation? As well as how do you arrive from the presentation to the cyclic decomposition (in cases that are not as trivial as this one)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your first question. This is a normal presentation, except with additive notation. The $\cdot^{ab}$ implicitly adds additional commutativity relations $a+b=b+a$, etc. As for the other question, going from presentation to cyclic decomposition can be done through fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups and/or Smith normal form.

Comment: What you want is "Smith Normal Form". You probably want a book on linear algebra or optimization algorithms, which should have the instructions for computing the Smith Normal Form. You can read off the invariant factor decomposition from the Smith Normal form. Search for "Smith Normal Form" in this site for some examples and explanations.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll take a look

Comment: @freakish Adding the equations gives $-4c=0$, not $c=0$. The group is $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/(4\mathbb{Z})$.